# how to type certain commands in vim, like CTRL-] ^Wc etc.. on a German Keyboard

Tags: windows, vim, keyboard-layout

I'm sitting here feeling silly - the vim help tells me to hit <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd><kbd>**]**</kbd> (to follow links in the help) and I can't get it!? Same problem with ^Wc (close a split window)

I have a German keyboard and especially the <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd><kbd>**]**</kbd> doesn't seem to work for me.

How do I do them?

Thanks for the help so far, seems to work except the <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd><kbd>**]**</kbd>! Any idea how I can make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a Croatian keyboard and pretty much the same problems (due to the fact that I don't have, for example "]" on it). Have you thought about remapping those keys to something which you could use instead of Ctrl-] key.

For example, plain *enter* works nicely for me.

To do that, you just go to your "/vimfiles/ftplugin/" directory, and create a file called help.vim (if you're interested in using that key combination only in HELP kind of files). In it, type

```
nmap <buffer> <Enter> <C-]>
"for just following the link
nmap <buffer> <C-Enter> <C-w><C-]><C-w>T
"for following the help topic in a new split (often useful)
```

Answer (score 7):

I think I found out myself. If I "pretend" to have an english keyboard and just click Ctr-+ (Ctr-"plus symbol") it seems to work. (to the left of "ü").

This is where the ] Symbol is on the English keyboard.

Make me wonder what else is mapped likethis? Anybody an idea?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. You're sure you don't have english layout set in your OS?

Comment: This worked for me in Neovim on Windows. But I do remember I tried this some years ago in Linux with regular vim and it didn't work.

Comment: Windows 10, German Keyboard Layout and NeoVim : Strg and "+" key work.

Answer (score 6):

First off, in this type of Help file, the `^` symbol indicates that you need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with the key. `^Wc` means to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, then `c` after releasing `^W`. It looks like you might need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>.

Secondly, `Ctrl` ("Control") should be equivalent to the `Strg` ("Steering"?) key on your German keyboard.

([Keyboard equivalents](http://carbon.cudenver.edu/~tphillip/GermanKeyboardLayout.html), for your reference. I imagine you *can* set up Vim to be friendlier to a German keyboard, but that exceeds my knowledge and Google-fu.)

Comment: Other equivalents: Esc (escape) == ^[, and M-x == "Escape, then x" == "Hold down Meta (usually Alt) and press x".  Sometimes "C-x" is written instead of "^X".  Though OP didn't ask for them, it still might be useful to know in the future...

Comment: As far as I know "Strg" = "Steuerung" in German (which pretty much translates to "Control" or "Steering")

Comment: I wouldn't re-map the controls to be friendlier to the German layout, simply because this would reduce your productivity on everything that's *not* set up that way.

Comment: Although I basically like how this site is put up, these "key" things are just terrible. Make reading the post almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In Vim you can use strg+click to follow a link as an alternative to ctrl+]. While this is not ideal it at least allows Vim beginners like me to navigate through the manual.

Comment: doesn't work in a terminal